# Call all records into an array of String

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I need to get all of records from TABLE_NOTES, Here is my method for calling all of records:

```
public List<NotesFragmentCreate> getAllNotes() {
    List<NotesFragmentCreate> notes = new ArrayList<NotesFragmentCreate>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NOTES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NotesFragmentCreate n = new NotesFragmentCreate();
            n.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_NOTES)));
            n.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            n.setCreated(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED)));
            n.setContent(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT)));

            // adding to note list
            notes.add(n);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return notes;
}
```

Then I create arrays in other class:

```
String[] title,created,content;

db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

List<NotesFragmentCreate> allNotes = db.getAllNotes();
for (NotesFragmentCreate note : allNotes) {
     //how can I get each of record to store in this array?
     title[?] = note.getTitle(); 
     created[?] = note.getCreated();
     content[?] = note.getContent();
}
```

Because I want to impement those arrays in a listView

```
adapter = new ListNotesAdapter(getActivity(), title, created);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple do as have variable inside loop shown as below.

Replace

```
String[] title,created,content;


List<NotesFragmentCreate> allNotes = db.getAllNotes();
for (NotesFragmentCreate note : allNotes) {
     //how can I get each of record to store in this array?
     title[?] = note.getTitle(); 
     created[?] = note.getCreated();
     content[?] = note.getContent();
}
```

with

```
List<NotesFragmentCreate> allNotes = db.getAllNotes();

    String[] title=new String[allNotes.size()];
    String[]  created=new String[allNotes.size()];
    String[] content=new String[allNotes.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (NotesFragmentCreate note : allNotes) {
         //how can I get each of record to store in this array?
         title[i] = note.getTitle(); 
         created[i] = note.getCreated();
         content[i] = note.getContent();
         i++
    }
```